# How to connect to FritzBox NAS

Tags: pantheon-files, networking

I want to connect to Fritz NAS over smb protocol. In Ubuntu it is easy.

```
Menu > File > Connect to server > "smb://fritz.box"
```

Then username and password.

And I am in.

How to do it with elementary OS?

Comment: I am not familiar with Fritz NAS, but connection with smb servers is possible using the "Connect to Server" option in the sidebar.  For smb choose "Windows Share".

Comment: Can  you see the server in the "Entire Network" view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a Fritz!box and I didn't use the NAS, until now.

This is how I got into the NAS today.
Just click on "Entire Network".

[image: EntireNetwork]

Open the FRITZ-NAS, and a "Wifi"-icon appears.

[image: Wireless Icon of Fritz-NAS]

And when you open this, a dialog box appears and you can fill in your credentials.
These are the credentials you gave in the setup of MyFritz.

[image: Dialog for credentials]

After login, your files on the NAS appear.